# When is the derivative of expectation the expectation of the derivative?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I am wondering what the conditions (if any) are for the derivative of an expectation to be equal to the expectation of a derivative:
$$
\frac{d E[X(t)]}{dt} = E \left[\frac{dX(t)}{dt} \right]
$$

where X(t) is some random variable.

Comment: seems like you need the distribution function of $X$ at time t ($f(x,t)$) to be differentiable at least.